# How to add Xampp to Zend Studio

Tags: zend-studio

I just installed Zend to try. On startup it asked me to point out the workspace. I pointed it out to `C:\xampp\htdocs`. Now i am trying to create a project and it asks me to add PHP Server. I never worked on any server except Xampp. But it doesn't show me Xampp Server.  Tried 
local ApacheHTTP server but i don't know what directory should i specify. Its not wokring on `C:\xampp\apache`

I dont need Xampp if i have zendstudio ?

Also how can i add xampp in servers of Zend Studio

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to select "Local Apache HTTP Server" then point it to your "conf" folder.